# How to set a variable that is a primary key in symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I want to instantiate a user with an username and password.

The username is the primary key in the database.

I have following code in symfony2:

```
            $username = $request->get('username');
            $email = $request->get('email');
            $password = $request->get('password');

            $user = new User();
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $user->setPassword(sha1($password));
            $user->setUsername($username);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
```

I get the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (email, password, money) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["testtttt@test.com", "61a9757ca7e9a5655e2d261298a04c983515b5b6", 1000000]:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'userName' doesn't have a default value
```

It seems that I can't call the setter on username because that is the primary key, but how can I give the variable a value then? Probably in the constructor but how does this work in symfony2?

Answer (score 0):

How is the `userName` defined in the entity, and as a table column? The mysql error tells, that "Field 'userName' doesn't have a default value", and Doctrine doesn't try to set a value as seen in the query. Is the entity property mapped as an [identifier](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys), and are you assigning a proper [generation strategy](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies) to `@GeneratedValue`, if it's present?
A quote from the docs about generation strategies:

> NONE: Tells Doctrine that the identifiers are assigned (and thus
>   generated) by your code. The assignment must take place before a new
>   entity is passed to EntityManager#persist. NONE is the same as leaving
>   off the @GeneratedValue entirely.

That could be the case. But it's hard to tell without looking at the entity definition.

Comment: /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
    
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

Comment: Is this what you mean?